# Turn off tooltip after clicking

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using Bootstrap native tooltip.

I have a link that shows a tooltip when moving the mouse over it using this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).on('hover', '#mylink', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

However the tooltip stays visible after I click on the link, that opens into a new window.

How can I turn off the tooltip after the click event using jQuery?

Comment: click event on which element ?

Comment: an a tag identified by #mylink id

Comment: jQuery(document).on('click', '#mylink', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose');
            });

Comment: i add the code above it turns off the tooltip but the link does not open anymore, how can i maintain the link opening in a new window ?

Comment: you want to hide or destroy ?

Comment: `jQuery(document).on('click', '#mylink', function(event) { 
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose'); 
});`

Comment: <a id="mylink" 
 href="anyurl" 
 target="_blank"
 data-toggle="tooltip" 
 data-placement="top">
 buy
</a>

Comment: just hide is good

Comment: `jQuery(document).on('click', '#mylink', function(event) { 
        jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide'); 
    });`

Comment: remove `event.preventDefault();` which prevents the default action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190938/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-angelo-rigo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dispose`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#tooltipdispose) method to destroy a tooltip

```
jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose')
```

---

For disabling tooltip for temporarly use [`disable`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#tooltipdisable) method later you can re-enable using [`enable`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#tooltipdisable) method.

```
jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose');
```

---

For hiding use [`hide`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#tooltiphide) method in tooltip.

```
jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
```

---

***UPDATE 1:*** Now combine this with the click event handler of that particular link. In addition to that trigger `blur` event (since it may be still focused) to hide the popover.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#mylink', function() { 
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide').blur(); 
});
```

Or even just triggering blur event would work for you since it's still active due to focusing.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#mylink', function() { 
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').blur(); 
});
```

---

***UPDATE 2:*** Or limit popover trigger on `hover` only by setting the trigger option.

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ trigger : 'hover'})
})
```